# Stochastic process, Fourier transform and $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question

Consider a time domain signal received at a sensor $x(t)$ over some time $t$, and we have performed Fourier transform on $x(t)$ to obtain $X(w)$. While performing Fourier Transform to find the frequencies are we under assumption that the time domain signal or function is from $L^2$ space? Is this assumption hidden or this assumption is not valid? Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The Fourier transform can be extended to all sorts of objects. But a natural setting is $L^{2}$ because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(s)|^{2}ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|^{2}dt$. And it's even more natural because the integral of the square of voltage or current is proportional to energy for a resistive load. Mathematically it may be convenient to wander into other spaces, but signal analysis should eventually bring you back to square integrable unless you're sucking away everyone's energy and then some.

Comment: @TrialAndError My interest may be in medium with no resistance as I am interested in far field wave. Consider, I have N number of complex samples from a sinusoidal, with noise of unknown frequency. I want to estimate the frequency of the wave so I looked at say 10N number of frequencies between 0 to 2pi using Fourier transform. Although there is only single sinusoid, Fourier Transform would show energy in many frequencies which are termed as spectral leakage.  My question was related to this:does  the spectral leakage, (which is due to compact window of time) is related to L2 assumption?